# Set image in imageview from gallery and save it?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I want to set an image from the Gallery to an ImageView and save it. So when I close the app and open it again the image from the ImageView should be the one I pick from the gallery.
Can you give me sample code on how to do it? I'm new to Android development.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your mainactivity:**

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
        String imgDecodableString;
     
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
     
        public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
            // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            // Start the Intent
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
        }
     
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            try {
                // When an Image is picked
                if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                        && null != data) {
                    // Get the Image from data
     
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
     
                    // Get the cursor
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    // Move to first row
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
     
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();
                    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
                    // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
                    imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                            .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));
     
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
     
        }
     
    }
```

Your Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ImageView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLoadPicture"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:onClick="loadImagefromGallery"
        android:text="Load Picture" >
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Permission for manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Is the external storage permission necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ImageView imageView;
private int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 123;
private String PREFS_NAME = "image";
private Context mContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        mContext = this;
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        String path = getPreference(mContext, "imagePath");

        if (path == null || path.length() == 0 || path.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

        } else {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(getScaledBitmap(path, 800, 800));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            setPreference(mContext, picturePath, "imagePath");
            imageView
                    .setImageBitmap(getScaledBitmap(picturePath, 800, 800));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Bitmap getScaledBitmap(String picturePath, int width, int height) {
    BitmapFactory.Options sizeOptions = null;
    try {
        sizeOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        sizeOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, sizeOptions);

        int inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(sizeOptions, width, height);

        sizeOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        sizeOptions.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, sizeOptions);
}

private int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    int inSampleSize = 0;
    try {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and
            // width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height
                    / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width
                    / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will
            // guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to
            // the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio
                    : widthRatio;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

boolean setPreference(Context c, String value, String key) {
    SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    settings = c.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    return editor.commit();
}

String getPreference(Context c, String key) {
    SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    settings = c.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    String value = settings.getString(key, "");
    return value;
}
```

}

Also add permission in manifest to Read External Storage.
I used shared preference to save the path of the selected image..you can also save the selected image in separate folder and save that folders path in preference.

Comment: how to save it in external storage?

Comment: you want save image in sd card?

Comment: yes or in internal ? and call that again to put in imageview

Comment: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/save-image-into-sd-card-in-android/ see this link to save image in sd card